# failing to eagerly initialize maps in hazelcast on startup

Tags: java, hazelcast

Currently I have two maps in hazelcast, and they are configured like so:

```
        <hz:map name="some-map"
            max-idle-seconds="0"
            time-to-live-seconds="0">
        <hz:map-store enabled="true"
                      initial-mode="EAGER"
                      write-delay-seconds="0"
                      class-name="SomeMapStore">
        </hz:map-store>
        <hz:partition-strategy>com.hazelcast.partition.strategy.DefaultPartitioningStrategy</hz:partition-strategy>
    </hz:map>
```

I would expect the `initial-mode="EAGER"` from the hazelcast-beans.xml configuration to populate the hazelcast map. Instead the application process hangs for a moment, and then I see the following error:

```
my-service 21:14:15.247Z [hz.my-service-name.SlowOperationDetectorThread] WARN  com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.slowoperationdetector.SlowOperationDetector - [localhost]:8085 [my-service-name-local] [3.9.4] Slow operation detected: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutTransientOperation
```

Has anyone run into this? I'm on hazelcast 3.9.4

Comment: Its not an error, its a warning saying that you have slow put ops in the cluster. Did you check SomeMapStore impl for the amount of time each of the method that runs DB queries were taking? If not then I’d say start with that as in most cases its the MapStore impl that slows down the cluster.

Comment: I've found more insight into the problem. It seems Hazelcast is trying to use the mapstore before spring has actually created it, and hazelcast is blocking until it loads everything, which of course never happens.